# Using type definition

Tags: go, types

In my code I have:

```
type Dimension big.Int
```

However, it is not clear to me how I can initialize a dimension object.
I know that I can create a big.Int object by doing:

```
i := big.NewInt(100)
```

However, how do I convert it to `Dimension`, or better, how can I initialized it directly as `Dimension`?

Comment: thank, I have updated it - I still don't understand how I can use it. Do I have to cast Amount to this type? How do I use it in practice?

Comment: How do you convert a byte b to an uint16? `uint16(b)`. That's a general rule.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The whole point of the `math/big` types is to use their methods, and you're removing the methods.

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
type Dimension big.Int
```

There is no way to declare a `Dimension` without using the `big` package's `Int` initializer, since it contains unexported fields.  So your best bet is to wrap the underlying initializer with your own:

```
func NewDimension(i int64) *Dimension {
    x := big.NewInt(100)
    z := Dimension(*x)
    return &z
}
```

Then call it as:

```
i := NewDimension(100)
```

Comment: what does it mean to have unexported fields?

Comment: @nick: Sounds like you should take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to get a grasp of basic concepts like exported and unexported fields in Go.

Comment: I obtain by running what you are showing `cannot convert big.NewInt(100) (type *big.Int) to type Dimension`

Comment: The error indicates you are returning a big.NewInt from a function which returns a Dimension